# There are 9 divs,I try to bind each of them click event,but everytime I click one, all of them like counts add1,how this happen?

Tags: jquery, ajax

There are 9 divs，called ".flag"，I bind click event on each of them.But evertime I click one of them, all the 9 counts changed.How this happen?I know there must be something wrong with my jquery code.

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//  
// var flaglist = $(".flag");
$(document).on("click", ".flag" ,function(){
    // 
    var count = $(this).find(".count").text();
    // 
    var id= $(this).parent().siblings().find(".ds-subtitle").attr("rel");
    alert(count);
    alert(id);

     $.ajax({
        url:"functions/php/like.php",
        type:"POST",
        // cache:false,
        data:{count:count,id:id},
        success:function(data){
            // alert(data);
            var str = data.split(",");
            var bool = str[0];
            var nums = str[1];
            // alert(nums);
            // console.log(data);
            if (bool == "0") {

                $("#popup-box1").show();
            } 
            if (bool == "1"){
                //  
                //  
                $("span .count").text(nums);   
            }
        }            
    });
});
});
```

php:

```
 <?php
 session_start();
 if (!isset($_SESSION["id"])) {   
    echo "0";       
 }else{
    echo "1"; 
    // 
    $id= $_POST["id"];
    //  
    $userid = $_SESSION["id"];
    // echo "string";
    $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "maroon5");
    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM fav WHERE user_id = $userid ";
    $res2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($res2) == 0) {
        // 
        $sql = " INSERT INTO fav (news_id,  user_id) 
             VALUES ('$id', '$userid') ";
        $res = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    }else{
        $sql_remove = "DELETE FROM fav WHERE user_id = $userid";
        $res_remove = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_remove);

    }       
    // echo "count++";
    // print_r($res);
    // 
    $sql1 = " SELECT * FROM fav WHERE news_id=$id ";
    $res1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
    $nums = mysqli_num_rows($res1);
    echo ",";
    echo $nums;

  }
  ?>
```

html(the first .flag):

```
<article class="grid-news">
    <header class="feature-wrapper">
         <div class="feature-background">
               <a href="#">
                   <img src="images/news/1.jpg" />
                </a>

          </div>
     </header>
      <div class="ds-card">
          <div>
              <h5>
               <!-- rel as news_id -->
                  <a class="ds-subtitle" href="#" rel="1">Maroon 5 & Kendrick Lamar's 'Don't Wanna Know' Tops Pop Songs Chart</a>
               </h5>
          </div>
           <div class="summary">
              <div class="post-name">
                  <span>Mar </span>
                   <span>23rd </span>
                   <span>2017 </span><br />
               </div>
           <div class="post-body">
               <p>We're announcing two new shows in Punta Cana, Dominican Republic &amp; Panama City, Panama....</p>
           </div>             
        </div>                              
     </div>
    <!-- automaticall update the like counts from database -->
    <?php
   $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "maroon5");      
    // 
    $sql1 = " SELECT * FROM fav WHERE news_id=1 ";
    $res1 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql1);
    $nums = mysqli_num_rows($res1);

    ?>
       <div class="post-footer">
           <div class="flag">
              <span class="flag-wrapper">
                  <a class="flag-action" href="#">
                   <i class="fa fa-heart-o" ></i>
         <?php
               echo "<span class='count'>". $nums  ."</span>";
          ?>
                  <!-- <span class="count">0</span> -->
                <span class="flag-text" >Like this news post</span>
               </a>
               </span>
             </div>
          </div>
     </article>
```

[click one of them](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pItQ7.jpg)

[after click,everyone changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYCAP.jpg)

Comment: Try binding the click event to `$(".flag").on("click", function() { ... });` vs. `$(document).on("click", ".flag", function() {...});`

Comment: @Forty3 I tried, it doesn't work.

Comment: When you click, how many alerts are you seeing? One for each .flag item or only one?

Comment: ooh, SQL injection opportunity! :)

Comment: if you need just one div to fire event, give unique id to each one. Now your divs have one class name and your event fired to each class element.

Comment: @LTulip - did you mean to hardcode the ID in the query `$sql1 = " SELECT * FROM fav WHERE news_id=1 ";` ?

Comment: The jQuery expression `$("span .count")` will select as many elements on the page that fulfill those criteria. If there are nine of them, all nine will be selected (and modified).

Comment: @Roamer-1888 - Nice catch. Totally missed that.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 Thank you , it works right now.

Comment: @Alnitak Thank you for your remind,I will fix it  right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery expression `$("span .count")` will select all elements on the page that fulfill those criteria. If there are nine of them, all nine will be selected (and modified).

You need to ensure that only the relevant `.count` element is selected.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.flag', function() {
        var $self = $(this);
        $.ajax({
            url: "functions/php/like.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                'count': $self.find(".count").text(),
                'id': $self.parent().siblings().find(".ds-subtitle").attr('rel');
            },
        }).then(function(data) {
            var str = data.split(',');
            if(!!Number(str[0])) {
                $("span .count", $self).text(str[1]); // <<<<<<< select only the relevant .count element
            } else {
                $("#popup-box1").show();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

You could similarly write `$self.find(".count")...` again.